# How do mmap region with MAP_PRIVATE work with a regular file?

Tags: linux, database, multithreading, mmap

Premise: For Linux. Do not need consider multiprocessing. Only care about multithreading within the same process and interact with the mmap area mapped to specific files on the disk with the flag set to `MAP_PRIVATE` and the permissions set to `PROT_READ` and `PROT_WRITE`.

Question:

1. If a thread modifies the data in the mapping area, can other threads immediately see the result of the modification?
2. Compared with "store the new value in the memory allocated on the heap, use `fwrite` to write to the disk, and then use `MAP_SHARED` mmap area to view the modification results.", modify the content on the `MAP_PRIVATE` mmap area, and then use `fwrite` sync to disk is more efficient, or worse?
3. Although the man document has the following description for `MAP_PRIVATE` "It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.", but if the disk file is modified in the way of question 2, even if the disk file is modified and `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` is called in this area, is it guaranteed that the modified content will be accessed?

Background:

1. Already read [man of mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).
2. I know the normal way to use is `MAP_SHARED` with file and `MAP_PRIVATE` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`.
3. Already checked the related questions on stackoverflow.